# SQL script create two separate columns from one

Tags: sql

I want to create two columns for Miles.  One for 'E' or "Empty" and one for 'L' or "Loaded" from columns labeled Miles and Loaded.

```
select
    billing_history.order_id,
    movement_order.order_id,
    movement_order.movement_id,
    movement.id,
    movement.loaded,
    Miles
from
    billing_history
left join
    movement_order on
        billing_history.order_id = movement_order.order_id
left join
    (
        select
            movement.id,
            movement.loaded,
            sum(movement.move_distance) as Miles
        from
            movement
        group by
            movement.id,
            movement.loaded,
            movement.move_distance
    ) movement on
        movement_order.movement_id = movement.id
where
    billing_history.delivery_date between '2014-07-01 00:00:00.000' and '2014-07-31 23:59:59.000'
```

Currently returns:

[image]

Would like to return:

[image]

I know how to do the group by Order and remove the Move ID. I just don't know how to get to the two columns "Loaded Miles" and "Empty Miles"?

Comment: Are we talking DDL or DML here? Please take more care to specify th nature of your problem.

Comment: sorry..I'm new to this. I don't want to change the database, I just want to pull the data into my SQL Query (excel) within the Transact SQL script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **case when** like below

```
Select Case when loaded = 'L' then miles else 0 end as loaded_mile,
Case when loaded = 'E' then miles else 0 end as empty_mile,
from billing_history;
```

Comment: @Kathy: Don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer if it helped you out. :)